# How do you hide the icons in the top right of PhpStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

In an update a while back PhpStorm (and presumably other JetBrains IDE's) added this top menu, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to disable and hide it. Their documentation is very confusing on what this section is even called.

[image: PhpStorm icons in the top right]

Is it possible to hide these? I am for reference using the Material UI theme, is it possibly being controlled by that?

Comment: FYI: You must be using the **new experimental UI**, which is still WIP (work in progress and not all aspects are highly customizable). It is not normally available to general users (unless Material UI has an option to activate it). 1) https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2022/05/take-part-in-the-new-ui-preview-for-your-jetbrains-ide/ 2) https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2022/06/addressing-the-new-ui-comments/ Not all aspects of it are customizable.

Comment: In any case: try checking available options in the "Main Menu | View" -- I would expect to have such an option to completely disable specific part there. Also: "Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Menus and Toolbars" -- all menus/toolbars that support customization should be handled here (not sure if the new UI is represented here -- I'm not using it).

Comment: P.S. I do not know if that part (top right side) is considered a Main Toolbar or some dedicated section (and therefore a separate entity to customize) but will mention this ticket anyway: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-287169